# PLSQL rollback changes made by procedure A from procedure B

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions, rollback

I have pls/ql procedure `procedure_test()`, this procedure changes some data in tables, and this procedure doesn’t have any commits or rollbacks.

So I call this procedure from another one - `procedure_test2()` after calling of `procedure_test()` from `procedure_test2()` all changes in `procedure_test()` are committed. So, how can I rollback changes made by `procedure_test()` from `procedure_test2()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code for both procedures; or preferably a minimal version that demonstrates the problem. Is `procedure_test` only doing pure DML, or is it also doing anything that might implicitly commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [savepoint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm) e.g. in procedure_test2() the code would be like

```
...
savepoint bforetest;
procedure_test(); 
rollback to savepoint bforetest; //this actually cancels whatever _test did.
...
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I have this error:
ORA-01086: savepoint 'BFORETEST' never established in this session or is invalid.

Comment: This could mean that procedure_test() performs either commit or rollback. because whenever rollback or commit is performed savepoints are erased. Bare in mind that commits can be implicit too.